# Problema con yum en CentOS 7: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: linux, unix, centos, centos7, yum

Cada vez que intento instalar algo con yum me da el mismo error. no consigo encontrar respuesta, tampoco consigo ver los repositorio instalados.

Si hago `yum repolist`     me aparecen, pero si busco en /etc/yum.rep.d/ no me sale nada

Error al intentar instalar algo con yum me sale lo siguiente.

```
[martin@localhost Descargas]$ sudo yum install notepadqq  
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                              |  22 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: mirrors.glesys.net
 * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * extras: mirrors.glesys.net
 * updates: mirrors.glesys.net
FedoraPeople-sea                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
base                                                                              | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
code                                                                              | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
docker-ce-nightly                                                                 | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
docker-ce-stable                                                                  | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
docker-ce-test                                                                    | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                            | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article 
https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors
If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.
If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.
 One of the configured repositories failed (added from: http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

    1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=ftp.altlinux.org_pub_distributions_ALTLinux_Sisyphus ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable ftp.altlinux.org_pub_distributions_ALTLinux_Sisyphus
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=ftp.altlinux.org_pub_distributions_ALTLinux_Sisyphus

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=ftp.altlinux.org_pub_distributions_ALTLinux_Sisyphus.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from ftp.altlinux.org_pub_distributions_ALTLinux_Sisyphus: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Comment: ¿has leído el artículo al que hacen referencia en el error? https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors
 Parece que hay que actualizar el repo

Comment: sii, he hecho lo que pone en el artículo y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Podrias indicar que version de SO tienes? centos7, que release?, y podrias ejecutar 'sudo grep -ir baseurl /etc/yum.repos.d/' para ver si te sale info de los repos?